# listCell setCellFactory function in javaFX: css style goes arbitrarily wrong

Tags: css, listview, javafx, auto-update

I'm building a server and client chat app using javaFX. For the chatting interface, I want to build a chat window that looks like this:
[image]

The first try of both sides (me and the chatting friend) goes very smoothly as shown in the picture above. However, things become really weirdly strange when they keep chatting:
[image]
[image]

[image]

Here are my code:

```
chatListView.setCellFactory(lv -> {
        ListCell<String> cell = new ListCell<>();
        Label label = new Label();
        cell.itemProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            if (newValue != null) {
                System.out.println(oldValue+ " " + newValue);
                String name = newValue.split(":")[0].toLowerCase();
                if (name.equals(pmUser)) {
                    label.setStyle("-fx-background-color: aliceblue;");
                    cell.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_RIGHT);
                }
                label.setText(newValue);
                cell.setGraphic(label);
            }
        });
        cell.emptyProperty().addListener((obs, wasEmpty, isEmpty) -> {
            if (isEmpty) {
                cell.setGraphic(null);
            }
        });
        cell.setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.GRAPHIC_ONLY);
        return cell;
    });
```

As you can see whenever a message belongs to the friend `name.equals(pmUser)` then css is changed. But the situation seems to be weird that it works only the first try of both sides. After that, everything is out of control.
Earlier I used the `updateItem(String item, boolean emtpy)` function but it also got the same problem.

Appreciate if someone can help me with this.

Comment: You need an `else` clause for your `if (name.equals(pmUser))` which resets the style and alignment.

Comment: What you mean about resetting is I need to set it back to the default? But may I know why the cell's style goes odd like that?

Comment: Update: Well I did try: 
`else {
                        label.setStyle("-fx-background-color: lightyellow");
                        cell.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_LEFT);
                    }`
And it still doesn't work

Comment: That seems weird. Can you create a [MCVE] that shows the problem, and [edit] your question to include it? Obviously not your whole project but just enough to be able to add strings to the list view with the two different users.

Comment: Oh my gosh, I just figured that out. Because my `pmUser` variable is wrongly assigned. Cuz I focused too much on the `setCellFactory` and ignored that. Truly sorry that I put a new question on this.